# Checking a two. dim. function for continuity in a non-zero point

Tags: calculus

if want to check a function like the following for continuity, we can argue, that we only have to check the point $(0,0)$ since for all other points, it is a composition of continuouse functions.

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0, & (x,y)=(0,0) \\ \frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \end{cases}$

So what we want is: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$

Which is kind of hard in eucledian coordinates since there are infinite possibilities to let $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

So we switch to polarcoordinates. We then let $r\to 0$ and check if the resulting limit depends on $\varphi$. If it does, we have a limit which depends on the direction we are approaching it, thus, we don't have continuity, if it doesn't, the function is continous in $(0,0)$ and thus in all points.

So far, so good. Let's consider another example. (I basically made it up, so I hope it "works". Since I can't really check it I don't know what point the following function should take in $(1,1)$ if it would be continous)

$g(x,y)=\begin{cases}0, & (x,y)=(1,1) \\ \frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}}, & (x,y)\neq (1,1) \end{cases}$

Anyway, assuming we want to check that function for continuitiy, what would we do?

My though is: Since we would like to do $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} g(x,y) = g(1,1)$ we would need the following in polarcoordinates:

$r\cos(\varphi)\overset{!}{=}1$

$r\sin(\varphi)\overset{!}{=}1$

This is only the case for $r=1$ or respective $\varphi$'s. So could I just change to polar coordiantes and check:

$\lim_{r\to 1} g(r,\varphi)$

Answer (score 0):

We have $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| \le \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This gives

$f(x,y) \to f(0,0)$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: Thansk for the answer but I don't see how that should answer my question. ( I do get the math, I just can't see how it answers the question.)